# No entiendo porque java netbeans no lee mis variables

Tags: java, formularios, calculo

Hola soy estudiante y empece hace poco y me acabo de crear una cuenta en la pagina. estoy intentando programar una calculadora científica en `javaforms` y no entiendo porque `Java NetBeans` no esta usando las variables que declare, creo que podría ser un problema con la clase pero no se muy bien del tema y es un código extenso así que no se donde esta el problema. una parte del código es este... muchas gracias por su atención,

```
            // Variables globales
        double n1;  
        double n2;
        double res;
        String val; 
        String operador;
        int cont=0;
    }     
     
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }
                      
    private void initComponents() {    


    private void escribir( String n ) {
        if( ! "0".equals( n )) {      // if( n != "0")
            cont++;
            if( cont == 1 ) {
                txtPantalla.setText( "" );
                txtPantalla.setText( n );
            }
            else {
                val = txtPantalla.getText();
                val += n;
                txtPantalla.setText( val );
            }
        }
        else if( cont > 0 ) {
            val = txtPantalla.getText();
            val += n;
            txtPantalla.setText( val );
        }
    }

    private void operacion( String op ) {
        operador = op;
        cont = 0;
        n1 = Double.parseDouble( txtPantalla.getText() );            
    }
```

Comment: Hola! Por qué dices que no funciona? Por favor describe mejor qué problema tienes con este código, qué intentas que pase y qué está pasando en su lugar. Ve a [edit] y complementa la pregunta, por favor

Comment: Justo toda esa parte del codigo, no demuestra tu problema...

Comment: Tienes que ayudarnos a ayudarte. Simplemente no poseemos acceso al proyecto como para probarlo y encontrar el problema.

Comment: Hola Luis Miguel, bienvenido, lo poco que muestras, tiene varios problemas, por el que preguntas, parece ser que las variables "globales", están declaradas dentro de algún método (están seguidas de un **`}`**)... osea que de globales nada, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y la enfoques en un problema, y adjuntes todo el código que "rodea" al mismo, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Comment: aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: de casualidad tus variables están en un bloque static? no se alcanza a apreciar con el código incompleto